# How to print #property value?

Tags: syntax, mql4

How do I access `#property` values from the code?

For example I'm having these:

```
#property description "Foo"
#property copyright   "bar"
#property link        "http://www.mql4.com"
#property version     "1.0"
```

I've tried to print it as follow:

```
Print(description);
```

but I've the error that it's *undeclared identifier*. Any ideas?

Comment: You may experience lot of surprises from the MetaQuotes, Inc., recent ***"modifications"*** of the language ( how the compiler handles formal substitutions, variable-names' restrictions ( at a **cost of a few man*years of efforts** burried in library revisions just to newly added restrictions in naming variables ... ), different code behaviour based on  syntax-sub-version-declarations via **`#property`** tag and many more hidden beasts ). After the last year of such hidden modifications I would recommend to stay on a safer side and be carefull on how much magic to rely on in MQL4.5(.6,.7 ... )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**WORKAROUND**: You cannot access/retrieve the `#property` values in MQL (not that I know anyway). However, there is a workaround with `#define`.
For example:

```
#define propDescription "Foo"
#define propCopyright   "bar"
#define propLink        "http://www.mql4.com"
#define propVersion     "1.0"

#property description propDescription
#property copyright   propCopyright
#property link        propLink
#property version     propVersion
```

... and later, in your code, you can access it with:

```
Comment( "Current Version: " + propVersion );
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: A nice workaround, Lee, indeed. Just one reminder from previous versions of these compile-time macro-substitutions processed by actual version of the `MetaLang.exe` MQL4 compiler. A few years ago, my team has spent some time on using similar macros for a light-weight version control of the MQL4-code-base. There were problems with an either undocumented or non-compliant behaviour of the `#define`-ed symbols. Even the double-quote-encapsulated strings did not work in accord with the actual MetaQuotes, Inc.,[[Help]]documentation. That experience made us be skeptical on some serious use of macros.